# Pivot Table on Excel - Summarize data

Tags: excel, pivot

Im working with a table similar to this one:

[image]

I want to create a pivot table that organizes the data by the "GRUPO" column, indicating the reason for leaving a company.

For example, in the table above, DK would have to have SALARIO = 2 (there are 2 people in group DK who between RAZÓN 1 and RAZÓN 2 have checked SALARIO).

I manage to do something like this:

[image]

But is not working correctly, as you see, i only want the final result for each RAZÓN...

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, there might be other ways to accomplish this task, however this is what i usually do, since i found it easy one for me, so you can follow the steps and refer image as well,

1.) Select any cell within the table i.e. your `ORIGINAL DATA SOURCE`,

[image: ORIGINAL SOURCE DATA]

2.) Now from `Data Tab` --> Goto --> `Get & Transform Data Group` --> From there click --> `From Table/Range`,

[image: DATA TAB - GET & TRANSFORM DATA]

3.) On selecting the one i have mentioned above, shall open the `Power Query Editor`,

[image: POWER QUERY EDITOR WINDOW]

4.) From Query Settings Panel, under `PROPERTIES` change the name to ***Grupotbl***

[image: Grupotbl]

5.) Now select any column and press `CTRL A` to select the whole table to change the data type, from `TRANSFORM TAB` --> Under Any Column Group --> Click Detect Data Type , this shall add one step in the `APPLIED STEPS` as *Changed Type*,

[image: CHANGED TYPE]

6.) Next select the first three columns and *right click* & select --> `Unpivot Other Columns`, eventually adding one steps under `APPLIED STEPS` as Unpivoted Other Columns

[image: UNPIVOTED OTHER COLUMNS]

7.) Now rename the column Value as `Razon`

[image: RENAMED COLUMN AS RAZON]

8.) Press CTRL and select the columns other than column named `Attribute` , right click `Remove Other Columns`,

[image: REMOVED OTHER COLUMNS]

9.) From `HOME TAB` under Close click the dropdown and click `Close & Load To`,

[image: CLOSE & LOAD TO]

10.) On doing above, you shall get this and click `Only Create Connection` and check the `Add this data to the Data Model` --> Press Ok,

[image: IMPORT DATA]

11.) From `Insert Tab` --> `Pivot Table` --> `From Data Model` --> You can either choose `New Worksheet or Existing Worksheet`, which ever suits you best, for this example i have selected existing worksheet cell A9

However you can also right click on the `QUERIES & CONNECTIONS` and click load to `Pivot Table Report` and Press Ok.

[image: INSERT TAB PIVOT TABLE]

[image: PIVOT TABLE FROM DATA MODEL]

[image: QUERIES & CONNECTIONS]

[image: PIVOT TABLE REPORT]

12.) So you see the Pivot Table layout has been created and you can also find the Pivot Table Fields Panel on the right side of your worksheet, From Fields panel you will find all the tables has been listed, select the Grupo Table --> Drag the Grupo Field in the Rows Areas while the Razon will be in the Values area respectively, you can change the layout design from design table, as well as from Report Layout change it to Show in Tabular Form.

[image: OUTPUT]

[image: LAST BUT NOT LEAST]

13.) In this manner you can `Transform` your data to [Summarize a Pivot Table](https://1drv.ms/v/s!AlEkksoPTc2cgwz6fKZYitadQPQG?e=agUgJM)!